# Python - How to balance classes before using classification mechanisms?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a dataset with unbalanced classes. Use "sklearn.StratifiedKFold" to split the data and then perform tests with various classification methods. The results are not good, possibly because of the unbalanced classes.

I did not find what libraries or methods to use to balance the classes previously. Some help? Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a good answer and tutorial:
[elitedatascience.com](https://elitedatascience.com/imbalanced-classes)

Techniques explained:
1. Up-sample Minority Class
Up-sampling is the process of randomly duplicating observations from the minority class in order to reinforce its signal.

There are several heuristics for doing so, but the most common way is to simply resample with replacement.

- First, we'll separate observations from each class into different DataFrames.
- Next, we'll resample the minority class with replacement, setting the number of samples to match that of the majority class.
- Finally, we'll combine the up-sampled minority class DataFrame with the original majority class DataFrame.

  2. Down-sample Majority Class
     Down-sampling involves randomly removing observations from the majority class to prevent its signal from dominating the learning algorithm.

The most common heuristic for doing so is resampling without replacement.
The process is similar to that of up-sampling. Here are the steps:

- First, we'll separate observations from each class into different
  DataFrames.

  - Next, we'll resample the majority class without replacement, setting the number of samples to match that of the minority class.
  - Finally, we'll combine the down-sampled majority class DataFrame with the original minority class DataFrame.